# How do you address someone in a case other than the vocative?

Tags: pronouns, noun, case, vocative

Suppose I'm talking to someone directly, and use a pronoun to refer to someone. I would use *tu* or *vōs* with an appropriate case based on its role in the sentence: for example, *sciō **tē** adesse*, "I know that **you** are here", with the accusative.

But what if I'm using a noun (such as a name or a description) along with that pronoun? My instinct is to put it in the same case. But a line from the Roman Missal is making me doubt that:

> *Confiteor Deo omnipotenti […] et vobis, **fratres***…
>   I confess to almighty God […] and to you, my **brothers**…

Here, *fratrēs* is in the vocative, even though *vōbīs* right next to it is dative.

Is this correct, by the standards of Classical Latin prose? And would it be incorrect to use *fratribus* instead?

(The quote is from the beginning of the *Confiteor*.)

Comment: First of all, a reminder. As Dickey 2002 puts it,  "Latin vocatives may be preceded or followed by a word meaning 'my' (*mi, mea, meum, meus, mei*, or *meae*) or 'our' *noster*" (p. 214). Most importantly, in your example, *vobis* is not used as a form of address but it's the indirect object of *confiteor*, that is why it's in the dative; vocatives are syntactically independent.

Comment: @AlexB. Oh inded; my question isn't why *vōbīs* is dative but why *fratrēs* **isn't** dative along with it.

Comment: because when it’s used as a form of address, it has to be in the vocative only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, forms of address are always in the vocative and are syntactically independent - they are extraclausal (Pinkster 2015: 1224).

However, appositives agree with the head (in case, gender, and number), so they are syntactically dependent.

Naturally, appositives can precede or follow vocative forms of address. Appositives will be in the morphological form determined by the syntax of the clause, whereas forms of address are always in the vocative.

> Appositives, in such cases, from the semantic point of view, "can be taken as descriptions ('you are X') rather than the address itself" (Pinkster 2016: 1226).

See the following examples from Pinkster 2015:

Mi Libane<sup>address.vocative</sup>, **ocellus aureus**, **donum decusque amoris**, amabo, faciam quod voles ... (Pl.) - a vocative construction *ocelle etc.* would be wrong here, because you are addressing Libanus, not the golden eye etc.

... ut... Romae essem **teque**, mi carissime et suavissime frater<sup>address.vocative</sup>, ad eam diem, ut sperabam, viderem. (Cic.)

see page 1226 in Pinkster 2016 for more examples.

Answer (score 6):

I think both constructions are possible, but do not have the same connotation.  *Confiteor Deo […] et vobis fratribus* would have a meaning like "I confess to God ... and to you (who are my) brothers"; but *Confiteor Deo […] et vobis, fratres*, "I confess to God ... and to you, O my brothers".  In other words, there is a change of focus in the latter, where the speaker momentarily addresses his audience.